# Batch Problems (making a dice)

Tags: batch-file, dice

This is my code in batch:

```
:Dice
set /a roll=(%random% %% 6) + 1
set /a on=%on%+%roll%
if %on%>19 goto DiceOver19
if %on%<20 goto Camp1_1
```

I'm trying to make a monopoly and i have almost everything setup.
I've been trying to figure this out but i just cant. Everything goes fine until i select "Roll the dice". ^^Above is the code for the dice.

The program just exits as soon as i go to Dice, can someone help?

EDIT: Fixed, now works fine.

Comment: You are missing the option /A on your second set statement. Read the help for the IF command.  Type: `IF /?` at a command prompt.

Comment: Still doesn't work, thanks for answering.

Comment: I have no idea what you changed.  If you changed your code then UPDATE your question.

Comment: You did not read the help for the `IF` command.  The < and > are not comparison operators in BATCH FILES.

Comment: How do i check then if %on% is higher then 19 or lower then 20?

Comment: @MarkoStamenkovic in a cmd console, `if /?`

Comment: What does the help for the `IF` command tell you to use for the comparison operators?

Comment: Oh, my bad, sorry.

Comment: From my knowledge of Monopoly, why would rolling 2 dice with a maximum of 6 per die produce a total of more than 19?

Answer (score 0):

Despite you having solved your own problem with the help of comments, I have added this reply which although technically not a direct response to your question includes a comparison operator and a standard roll loop which allows for a roll again feature in the event of rolling a double six. *(I hope it at least benefits others)*

```bat
@Echo Off
:Roll
Set "dice=0"
:Loop
Set/A "die1=%random%%%6+1"
Set/A "die2=%random%%%6+1"
Echo( %die1% + %die2%
Set/A "dice=die1+die2+dice"
Set/A "mod=dice%%12"
If %mod% Equ 0 (Echo= Double 6 rolls again & GoTo Loop)
Echo( Total=%dice%
:Next
Timeout 3 1>Nul
```

Note this is for information only.